# RewriteRule not working with the word i want

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, cpu-word

Hello today i was changing my urls and every single one went well but this one is not accepting the word i want.

Here's is the code line:

`RewriteRule    ^organizador/?$    organizador/index.php    [NC,L]`

Strange thing happening: 
if i change the `^organizador/?$` to `^org/?$`it works.

And i'm sure that htaccess is working because i have other urls and i also tried to throw junk at the code and it gives me the error code 500 successfuly.

Any idea why it happens with that word only?

**Full .htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On    # Ligar a função de rewriting


RewriteRule    ^organizador/?$    organizador.php    [NC,L]   # Reconhecer "organizador"

# URL principal
RewriteRule    ^/?$    index.php    [NC,L]    

# URL principal
RewriteRule    ^inicio/?$    index.php    [NC,L]    

# URL para administração
RewriteRule    ^admin/?$    admin.php    [NC,L]   

        #Conta

# URL para activar a conta
RewriteRule    ^conta/activate/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   conta/activate.php?user=$1&cod=$2   [NC,L]   

# URL para sair da conta
RewriteRule    ^logout/?$    logout.php    [NC,L]   

# URL para entrar na conta
RewriteRule    ^login/?$   login.php   [NC,L]   

# URL para login com erro
RewriteRule    ^login/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   login.php?erro=$1   [NC,L]  

# URl para criar conta
RewriteRule    ^registar/?$    registar.php    [NC,L]    

# URL para visualizar o perfil
RewriteRule    ^conta/?$    conta/perfil.php    [NC,L] 

# URL para visualizar o perfil
RewriteRule    ^conta/perfil/?$    conta/perfil.php    [NC,L] 

# URL perfil com 1 entrada
RewriteRule    ^conta/perfil/([A-Za-z]+)/?$    conta/perfil.php?opcao=$1    [NC,L] 



        #Eventos

# URL para ver os eventos          
RewriteRule    ^eventos/?$    eventos/index.php    [NC,L]   

# URL eventos com 1 entrada
RewriteRule    ^eventos/inicio/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$  eventos/index.php?tipo=$1    [NC,L]

# URL eventos com 1 entrada
RewriteRule    ^eventos/inicio/([0-9-]+)/?$  eventos/index.php?page=$1    [NC,L]  

# URL para criar eventos
RewriteRule    ^eventos/criar/?$    eventos/criar.php    [NC,L]   

#  URL criar com 1 entrada
RewriteRule    ^eventos/criar/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   eventos/criar.php?opcao=$1   [NC,L]

#  URL para visualizar eventos detalhadamente
RewriteRule    ^eventos/visualizar/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   eventos/visualizar.php?evento=$1   [NC,L]

#  URL para visualizar eventos detalhadamente
RewriteRule    ^eventos/visualizar/?$   eventos/visualizar.php   [NC,L]

#  URL para inscrever nos eventos
RewriteRule    ^eventos/inscrever/([0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([0-9-]+)/?$   eventos/inscrever.php?evento=$1&tipo=$2&passo=$3   [NC,L]

#  URL para inscrever nos eventos 2 campos
RewriteRule    ^eventos/inscrever/([0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$   eventos/inscrever.php?evento=$1&tipo=$2   [NC,L]

#  URL para inscrever nos eventos 1 campo
RewriteRule    ^eventos/inscrever/([0-9-]+)/?$   eventos/inscrever.php?evento=$1  [NC,L]



        #Administração

# URL para ver a administração          
RewriteRule    ^administracao/?$    administracao/index.php    [NC,L]   



        #Organização

# URL para ver o painel de organizador   
RewriteRule    ^organizado/?$    organizador/index.php    [NC,L]
```

I'm sorry about all the portuguese words, if you have any doubt just point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you have 2 **contradictory** rules.

**Rule one:**

```
RewriteRule    ^organizador/?$    organizador.php
```

**Rule two:**

```
RewriteRule    ^organizador/?$    organizador/index.php    [NC,L]
```

Only **first one will work** because that converts request URI to `organizador.php` hence 2nd one never fires.

Comment: My code on the top of the .htaccess looks like this now: `Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On ` and still doesnt work

Comment: Then you might be having .htaccess inside `organizador` as well

Comment: Inside the folder "organizador" there is only the page index.php

Comment: Added, sorry about that

Comment: You are right, thank you for your time, i guess we turn blind after seeing the code many times